# Can't figure out how to display every step of a looped equation in python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops, equation

My friend is in a python class online that has failed to teach him the basic he needs to know in order to advance. These are the HW problems he has due tonight - wondering if anyone can help with figuring out the solutions.

The first problem is really tripping us up. This is what we have so far, but it doesn't accomplish what is requested in problem 1:

```
total = 0
Max = len(range(1,11))
for cnt, i in enumerate(range(1,11)):
  total += i
  if cnt == Max-1:
    print(i, end=" = ")
    print(total)
  else:
    print(i, end=" + ")
```

Alternatively, we have this, but this also doesn't accomplish the goal of the question.

```
for x in range(1,11):
   for y in range(1,11):
        r = x * y
        print(x, "*", y, "=", r)
```

Refer:

[image]

Comment: Please describe the problem with words, not image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
numbers = []
for e in range(0,10):
    numbers.append((numbers[-1] if numbers else 0) +1)
    print(" + ".join(map(str, numbers)) + " = %d" % (sum(numbers)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should works!

```
for cnt in range(2,12):
  Sum=0
  for i in range(1, cnt):
    Sum+=i
    if i==cnt-1:
      print(i, end =" ")
    else:
      print(i, end =" + ")
  print('=',Sum)
```